# Informix instance not starting

Tags: informix

When I tried to start the Informix instance in Linux using `oninit`, it says

```
WARNING: server initialization failed, or possibly timed out (if -w was used).
Check the message log, online.log, for errors.
```

Log says:

```
13:10:30 IBM Informix Dynamic Server Started.
13:10:30 Insufficient free huge pages in /proc/meminfo for shared memory segment.
Requested: 2610302976 bytes. Available: 0 bytes.
The default memory page size will be used.
13:10:30 Segment locked: addr=0x44000000, size=2610302976
13:10:30 Insufficient free huge pages in /proc/meminfo for shared memory segment.
Requested: 1048576000 bytes. Available: 0 bytes.
The default memory page size will be used.
13:10:30 Segment locked: addr=0xdf961000, size=1048576000

13:10:33 Event alarms enabled. ALARMPROG = '/opt/informix/etc/alarmprogram.sh'
13:10:33 Booting Language  from module 
13:10:33 Loading Module 
13:10:33 Booting Language  from module 
13:10:33 Loading Module 
13:10:39 DR: DRAUTO is 0 (Off)
13:10:39 DR: ENCRYPT_HDR is 0 (HDR encryption Disabled)
13:10:39 shmget: [EEXIST][17]: key 52564803: shared memory already exists
13:10:39 (2) shm creation of shmem segment failed
13:10:39 Trusted host cache successfully built:/etc/hosts.equiv.
```

`onclean` shows:

```
 - Looking for semaphore ID: 950274
 - Looking for the shmem key: 52564801
 - Looking for the shmem key: 52564802
```

`oninit -v` shows:

```
 6136
Reading configuration file '/opt/informix/etc/onconf.cars'...succeeded
Creating /INFORMIXTMP/.infxdirs...succeeded
Checking config parameters...succeeded
Allocating and attaching to shared memory...succeeded
Creating resident pool 1494788 kbytes...succeeded
Allocating 1024016 kbytes for buffer pool of 2K page size...succeeded
Creating infos file "/opt/informix/etc/.infos.jensuse02"...succeeded
Linking conf file "/opt/informix/etc/.conf.jensuse02"...succeeded
Initializing rhead structure...succeeded
Writing to infos file...succeeded
Initialization of Encryption...succeeded
Initializing ASF...succeeded
Initializing Dictionary Cache and SPL Routine Cache...succeeded
Bringing up ADM VP...succeeded
Creating VP classes...succeeded
Forking main_loop thread...succeeded
Initializing DR structures...succeeded

WARNING: server initialization failed, or possibly timed out (if -w was used).
Check the message log, online.log, for errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one (or more) of the shared memory segments already exists; there wasn't a clean shutdown.  Use `onclean` — it should clean up for you.

When you restart, consider using 'verbose' mode: `oninit -v`.  It will report what it is doing until the server is up and running.